# fancyBox 2: formatting title

Tags: jquery, fancybox

For fancyBox 1.x there was an info how to format a title. I'm missing this for the new version...

I want to add a title like "Image 1 of x. You can find the hole gallery here [=link]"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For fancybox v2.0.x you could customize/format the `title` using the `beforeShow` option like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   beforeShow : function() {
    this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '') + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + '. You can find the whole gallery  <a href="/parth/to/gallery">here</a>';
   }
}); // fancybox
```

Answer (score 0):

did you see the [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) page

the option called

`title` -   Overrides title content, accepts any HTML